# How to render gouraud shading?

Tags: rendering, shaders

Is there a way to render gouraud shading in blender? Or a shader setup that would extremely closely mimic gouraud shading? If not, what other solutions might there be for what I'm looking for? I'm asking cause it's needed for old style things I want to make, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to go about this, if it's even possible in modern blender.

Comment: You can do Gouraud shading (or similar) with Blender Internal as a render engine ; so, with an old version of Blender (prior to 2.8)